# What does the CHOLMOD error mean and how do I solve it for my mixed linear regression model?

Tags: lme4, emmeans

I am running a mixed regression model

```
lmer(Shock.ct.cumPeriod ~ tlag + Grazing_strategy +
                (1|Stocking_rate)+(1|Year), data = d.shock2b)
summary(m.shock)
```

and then using the emmeans function from the emmeans package to do a get a mean separation test.

```
emm.mshock
```

After which, I get this error
`Error in t(ZZ) %*% EE %*% ZZ :  CHOLMOD error 'problem too large' at file '../MatrixOps/cholmod_ssmult.c', line 222`

I just updated R and all of the packages, and saw a recent post in the exchange concerning incompatible binaries between the LME4 and Matrix libraries. One issue was resolved after following the suggested steps and reinstalling all packages, however, this issue is still presenting. Any help would be appreciated.